# Select one compulsory record plus several optional

Tags: sql, select

I want to select one record compulsory plus optional records if they exists. I was able to achieve it using this script:

```
SELECT user_id from USERS 
  WHERE user_id = 1
  AND title IN ('web developer')
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id from USERS 
  WHERE user_id <> 1
  AND title IN ('web developer')
```

I wonder if there are a better ways to do it ?

Comment: what is optional and compulsory here?

Comment: User record with a user_id = 1 is compulsory, other records are optional

Comment: How is this query any different from `SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE title = 'web developer'`? I don't understand what you are trying to do and I don't understand, from your example what "Compulsary" and "Optional" mean. Please elaborate.

Comment: `SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE title = 'web developer'` not necessarily selects a user record with user_id = 1. I want my query to return that record + some other records if they exists.

Comment: @user3715778 But what happen if compulsory record doesnt exists? You still will get records

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza I _know_ it exists

Comment: I guess the compulsory is the top one?

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza, yes sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will prove JNevill comment, your querys are equivalent to a single query.

Lets imagine there are only 10 users and `id` is a primary key so no duplicated, one user is `Id = 1` and also is a `'web developer'`

So first query will bring you one record.

Now second query will check for all the rest user (9) to see who is also a `'web developer'`.

So with both querys you will check for all 10 user to see who is a `'web developer'`

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM users 
WHERE title = 'web developer'
```

NOTE:

Another simplification if `id` is a primary key and you know is there.

Why do  `SELECT user_id from USERS WHERE user_id = 1 ...` if you know the result is `1`

Comment: dont worry, I have been there and sometimes overcomplicated simple things.

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on where a UNION may make sense in the "Compulsary" vs "Optional" idea that you are coming from. (adding as answer since it's too wordy for a comment). There might be a use for the `UNION All` if you needed to elaborate on why the particular record was selected, like:

```
SELECT user_id, 'compulsary' as reason from USERS 
  WHERE user_id = 1
  AND title IN ('web developer')
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, 'optional' from USERS 
  WHERE user_id <> 1
  AND title IN ('web developer')
```

Where your user_id is supplied by a parameter, this might make some sense. But even in this scenario you could use a single query:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    CASE WHEN user_id = 1 THEN 'compulsary' ELSE 'optional' END as reason 
FROM USERS 
WHERE title IN ('web developer')
```